# Compute $f(x) \mod N$ for $f(1)=2^2-1;f(x)=f(x-1)^2-1$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Take a look at the definition of $f(x)$

$f(1) = 2^2-1$
$f(x) = f(x-1)^2-1$

Is there any quick way that I can use in order to compute 
$$f(x)  \mod N$$
$N$ is a big composite integer such that factoring it is hard.

Comment: The quadratic map $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 - 1$ with $x_0 = 2$. unfortunately doesn't have a closed form (to the best of my knowledge). Also, since $N$ is large, cycle finding won't usually do so well. You say that factoring $N$ is hard, so I assume it has no small prime factors, which is also a bummer.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003096 it does have a solution of the form $\left\lceil c^\left(2^x\right)\right\rceil$, but $c$ isn't easy to compute.

Comment: @DanielV can you please show me where do you see this solution? I don't see it in the link you attached.

Comment: Under "Formula"

Comment: @DanielV I stand corrected

Comment: @MohamadAliBaydoun You aren't wrong.  Computing $c$ may be difficult enough to treat it as not having a closed form.